# Multiple, separate rel= tag attributes OK? (WordPress)

Tags: html, wordpress, nofollow, rel

Is having two separate rel="" attributes in an a tag OK?

It seems WordPress by default adds a rel="nofollow" tag to all external links. In the code these are added to the very beginning of the a tag.

In order to add rel="me" attributes to my social profiles on my About page (where my rel="author" links point to), I've added some [tweaks as suggested by Yoast](http://yoast.com/wordpress-rel-author-rel-me/).

The resulting code looks as follows:

```
<a rel="nofollow" title="XYZ" href="http://link.com" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','http://link.com']);" rel="me nofollow">Google Profile</a><br />
```

Note the rel="nofollow" at the beginning, and then the rel="me nofollow" towards the end of the a tag. The attributes at the end are hand-coded, the initial one is the WordPress default.

Is having two instances of rel="" acceptable? If so, should I get rid of the duplicate nofollow attribute in the second one?

I'm not seeing my blog properly linked to my Google Profile, checked via Google's [SGAPI Recrawl Tool](https://sgapi-recrawl.appspot.com/), however the attributes seem to have been picked up by the Rich Snippets testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [w3c Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) tool to tell whether html is valid. Duplicate attribute names are invalid html. Get rid of the first one and just use your second tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I discovered the rel="nofollow" tag was actually being added by a setting for a plugin, not by WordPress itself.

Comment: Can you share the name of the plugin that was causing this issue? We also have a customer who is facing the same problem, but he is unable to find the solution.